# How can I list all the direct message groups where myself and a given user belong to in Slack?

Tags: search, slack

I want to list the direct message groups where at least myself and another user belong to in Slack. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reddit user [beyondholdem](https://www.reddit.com/user/beyondholdem) [pointed](https://redd.it/y43avs) me to the following solution:

> Use the search bar with a , (comma) and you don't even need to use their entire name.

E.g.:

[image]

Limitation: only shows the most recent 10 results.

Reddit user [zachlab](https://www.reddit.com/user/zachlab) [mentioned](https://redd.it/y43avs) the Slack API:

> - `user.conversations.list`, find all ims and mpims.
> - `conversations.members` to list members of those mpims.